# formatting a string for ssh argument - Python

Tags: python, string

This question may be silly, but I hate when a programming language does it on me ... so I have the following function:

```
def udp_server(client=""):
    mutex.acquire()
    try:
        print "Starting server ... "
        server_process = subprocess.Popen("iperf.exe -s -u -i 1 -l 872",
                                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        print "Server started at ", server_process.pid
        print "Starting the client remotely on %s" % client
        cmd = "cd C:/performance/Iperf && python iperf_udp_client.py -c %s" % client
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
        client.connect(str(client), username=str(config['ssh_user']),
                       password=str(config['ssh_pwd']))
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
        print stdout.readlines()
        server_process.kill()
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    finally:
        mutex.release()
```

`config` is loaded when the function is loaded ... the values are assigned to a `mode.config` file, which parses nicely into `config` (I did test it )

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {}
    execfile('C:\performance\mode.config', config)
    main()
```

When I hardcoded the values into `client.connect()` it worked nicely, however, when I try to make it in the correct way (using a config file, instead of hardcoding), I get the following error:

```
Starting the client remotely on 123.456.795
getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None
```

Of course `client` is a String: `client = config['client']`. Could someone please help me? The Python versions is `2.7.5`.

Comment: I'm confused, what is your question?

Comment: `client.connect(str(client), ...)` looks rather suspicious. How could the `str` of a `SSHClient` instance be useful?

Comment: As a side note, using plain string literals and Windows backslash paths together is a recipe for disaster, and even worse if you have lowercase directory and file names. At some point, you're going to try to open a file named `'C:\performance\new.config'`…

Comment: Yeah. Also, `123.456.795` is not a valid IP address, double check your config! Python is not "playing a trick" on you... It's pretty much the contrary.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Of cocurse `123.456.795` is not a valid IP. I just didn't want to right the actually ip, but I think it was pretty clear the IP address wasn't the issue

Comment: @nneonneo I tried without `str()` before and I got the same error :-(

Comment: What nneonneo and abarnert say is, though.

Comment: `str()` is not the issue, the issue is that `client` is not the string you loaded with `client = config['client']`, but the `SSHClient` instance you assigned in the code posted above. Rename one of the two.

Comment: @abarnert then I hardcoded the values into `client.connect()` it worked file ... if I use the dictionary or pass the values in the function header I get the same problem

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo It worked!  thank you ... please make your comment an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting `client = config['client']` definition (which is what you have in mind) with `client = paramiko.SSHClient()`. Rename one of the two variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have named two distinct variables both `client`: the hostname of the client you want to connect to, and the `SSHClient` instance you are using to connect.

When you do

```
client.connect(str(client), ...)
```

you are effectively passing the `str` of the `SSHClient`, rather than the hostname of the client. This will result in a failure to resolve the hostname (which probably looks like `<SSHClient instance at 0xdeadbeef>`).

You can resolve this by renaming one of your variables. For example, you can call the host name `hostname` instead of `client`.